# Bootstrap.css file not reflecting changes

Tags: css

i have a default bootstrap.css file.I am trying to change an item with in but its not reflecting my changes.

the bootstrap file i want to change

```
@media(min-width:1200px) { // i want to change the width to 1450px,when i change it here it still refelects as 1200px when the page is run.
.col-lg-6 {
    width: 50%;
}
```

}

i tried to add it into my own css document

```
@media(min-width:1450px) { //doesnt get picked up
    .col-lg-6 {
        width: 50% !important;
    }
}
```

is there any suggestions?

Comment: CTRL+F5 in the browser?

Comment: hard refresh,i have done that

Comment: It's better to modify classes in your own css file, loaded after bootsptrap. 
It seems like your css is cached. Clear browser cache and test back.

Comment: i did a hard refresh and emptied cache,but its not taking in the change

Comment: Just check your browsers console to figure out whats going wrong. Question is too broad now. Maybe you're screen isn't that big, maybe its because you designed the layout in a particulair wrong way, maybe the file is not correctly included .. etc

Comment: Check your browser window width :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking it after 1450px width?

Your css won't change what happens between 1200px and 1450px width.